# MainProject is always expected to update a class library resource string

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-resources, xamarin

When I created a project in Visual Studio 2012 where Xamarin is installed, I choose Android Application as the project's template.

Later, I added an Android class library to the solution. The class library has a string resource. The main project has a reference to the class library.

Every time I build the solution, the main project's resource designer's `UpdateIdValues()` method is always populating its content automatically (I erased it over and over again) and it's expecting that the main project has the same resource string and it should update the class library resource string!

[image]

I dont want my main project's resource designer to be updated this way. My main project will never have the same resource string as the class library' and it should never update any class library' resource string.

I dont know if there's a setting property that i missed but is there a way to (fix) properly handle this scenario? (Im new to android and xamarin)

Comment: Same issue here. But I am using Xamarin Studio for Mac. I could fix it by file-linking all resources from the library inside the application main project. But I did it just in order to have my project temporarily running while researching for the real solution. I am also needing an answer. Question Upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

This is done to synchronize the Library with the Application Project. The Main App needs to know about the Resources in the Library project, so the Xamarin tools create ID's for everything that is in the Library in the the Main Application project, and runs `UpdateIdValues()` which updates the Id's in the Library project as well.

However in Mono for Android that is a bit broken where `UpdateIdValues()` is not called, hence the Id's mismatch.

When using a Library for Resources you need to make sure that everything is in lowercase. That works very well for me in L[egacyBar](https://github.com/Cheesebaron/LegacyBar). Check that project out for how it can be done.